# Retrieve data from models having reverse relationship in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models where model A has foreign key of another in reverse order like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
img=models.CharField(blank=True)
category=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)

class Section(models.Model):
book= models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='sections', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
title= models.TextField(null=True)

class SubSection(models.Model):
section=models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='subSections', 
                           on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True) 
sub_title= models.TextField(null=True)
```

I am trying to fetch all sections and subsections on the basis of book id. Before I was using nested serializer but nested serializer slow down its response.
i am trying to achieve it with select_related can anyone help me with view query and serializer class. I want response like:

```
data=[
  "section": "A",
  "title": "intro",
  "subsection": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sub_title": "title"
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before I was using nested serializer but nested serializer slow down its response.

The nested serializer itself does *not* slow down the response, this simply because it will result in an *N+1* problem: you need to load the related data in *bulk*.

You can use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for this, so:

```
Section.objects.prefetch_related('sections')
```

This will load `SubSection`s of the selected `Section`(s) in *bulk*.

It however does not make much sense to use `'sections'` for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), since this is the name of the relation in reverse. You thus might want to rename this to:

```
class SubSection(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(
        Section,
        related_name='subsections',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    sub_title= models.TextField()
```

and thus prefetch with:

```
Section.objects.prefetch_related('subsections')
```

Comment: first of all thanks to help me out and I have corrected related name in question but the result of your query is list of section queryset the problem that I was facing in fetch subsections by using those queryset

Comment: @RichaTiwari: you still need to use the subserializer: but now it will no longer result in an *N+1 query problem*.